# how to add line break or newline for space in specific columns using kable extra r-markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, pdflatex, kableextra, stargazer, gt

I'm using r-markdown to generate pdf. i want to add a line break or newline to a column in a dataframe where ever the space is there

```
C1       C2    ID
-----------------
22.6    a-b    a
23.5    ba-cd  b
24     c-d     c
25.3    d-e    d
```

i want output like

```
C1     ID
------------
22.6   a
a-b

23.5   b
ba-cd
```

my code

```
df$C1<- with(df, paste0(C1,'\n', C2))

df$C2<-NULL

kbl(df,booktabs = T,longtable = T,align = c("c", "c", "c", "c")) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"),bootstrap_options = "bordered",font_size = 7,full_width = F)%>%
  column_spec(1, width = "8cm")%>%
  column_spec(2:4, width = "2.25cm")%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#008752")
```

Comment: It's easier to reproduce your output if you add the content of `df` in a nicer format :-)

Comment: actually ID will remain unchanged, i have combine c1 and c2 by seperator '\n' so it has to add linebreak  and c2 values should come below C1 values  @RonakShah

Comment: @RonakShah I have mentioned what's required for changes. please have a look i have edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<br/>` tag for linebreak -

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df$C1<- with(df, paste0(C1,'<br/>', C2))

df$C2<-NULL

kbl(df, booktabs = T,longtable = T,align = c("c", "c"), escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"),
                bootstrap_options = "bordered",font_size = 7,full_width = F)%>%
  column_spec(1, width = "8cm")
```

[image]

Comment: ```22.6 <br/>a-b``` i'm getting like this . can we use <br/> in pdf generation of r-markdown

Comment: Ohh..for pdf you need to use `linebreak` function. Try with -  `df$C1<- with(df, paste0(C1,'\n', C2));df$C1 <- linebreak(df$C1)`.

Comment: ```\makecell[l]{22.6\\a- b}``` i'm getting like this. Inplace of '\n' i tried \linebreak, \t etc